# Control how many times a TableViewCell is outputted to the TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

regarding `UITableView`'s I am having some problems. Putting it simply, I have a data array with user inputted numbers and a table view with 2 sections: one section for total count of the array, and the other for each of the numbers in the array. This project's code is too long and complex for me to slap up and ask for a simple code fix, so this will be a more generalized question.

When the cells output to the screen, they are in the correct format (outputting to the proper section and cell in the `TableView`). The second section outputs each number in the array with one number in each row, but the top section repeats "The total amount of numbers is: *_*" in a new row every time a new number is inputted or written in the second section below it.

**For example:**

The table should look like -

The total amount of numbers is: 3

1

2

6

**But what actually ends up happening is:**

The total amount of numbers is: 3

The total amount of numbers is: 3

The total amount of numbers is: 3

1

2

6

How do I control the amount of times the first section is outputted, while still leaving the second section determined by `[array count]` in the `numberOfRowsInSection:` method?

**If you need further clarification feel free to ask, I know it is pretty vague.

****UPDATE****

Now I need to get rid of the "index 0 beyond bounds of empty array" error message when the user inputed array is nil. Here is the code for the `numberOfRowsInSection:` method thus far:

```
       if (timeline != nil){
       int a = 0;
       switch (section) {
           case 0:
               a = 1;
               break;

           case 1:
               a = timeline.count;
               break;
       }

       return a;
    }

    else {
        return 1;
    }
```

What should I change further to prevent both problems from occurring?

Comment: Without seeing your relevant table view data source methods there is no good answer to give you.

Comment: There are too many files used in this `UIViewController` from a `#import` that the variables in my code would only clutter and distract the readers from my actual question. This is why there is no sample code, as it would take too long to explain where all the variable names are coming from, how they are inputted, etc.

Comment: I said "relevant code". All you needed to post was your `numberOfRowsInSection:` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined two sections, so inside 
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

```
if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return [SomeArray count];
    }
```

In case you want to add separate headers for each table section, the pattern is similar:
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

```
if (section ==0 ) {
    return @"Title For Section 1";
} else {
    return @"Title For Section 2";
}
```

}

Comment: I'd say it's preferable to use a `switch`-`case` statement for this purpose, but otherwise, this is the right idea.

Comment: this is the best way.

Comment: I'll agree with Isaac and leave it to momodude22 to determine his coding style :). Otherwise, the main idea is that you can determine how many rows for each section, by checking the section number (beginning with 0 of course).

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was on the brink of it, but thank you soooooo much!

Comment: One more tip. You can add separate titles for each section too. I'll edit my answer to include.

Comment: So the answer you provided works, but there was a hidden error I overlooked. My array that I am using is user inputted, so as long as the array is not nil, it works. But now, if the user simply does not enter values, I get an error stating "index 0 beyond bounds of empty array". If I simply change the `return 1;` line back to `return [someArray count];` there is no error, but the doubling in the `UITableView` returns. Any idea what I could do to satisfy both situations?

Comment: I've been down that road before too. :) You need to make - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView conditional!
{
    if (some Bool) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}

Comment: I have added the updated code in the problem, please take a look at it. And seriously, thank you so much for all of the help! I really do appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to output only 1 cell in the first section, so you could do something like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return section == 0 ? 1 : arrayName.count;
}
```

This would output 1 cell in the first section, and a number equal to the array length for the second section. Hope this helps you!